# Modified stress-energy tensor of a scalar field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Let $\Theta_{\mu \nu}$ be the canonical tensor of a scalar field $\phi(x)$. Consider the following modification

$$ \Theta^{'}_{\mu \nu} = \Theta_{\mu \nu} + a(\partial_\mu \partial_\nu - g_{\mu \nu} \Box) \phi^2$$

where $a$ is constant. I have to prove that if $\Theta_{\mu \nu}$ is conserved, so is $\Theta^{'}_{\mu \nu}$. I proceeded as follows.

$$ \partial^\mu \Theta^{'}_{\mu \nu} = \partial^\mu \Theta_{\mu \nu} + \partial^\mu  a(\partial_\mu \partial_\nu - g_{\mu \nu} \Box) \phi^2$$
$$ = \partial^\mu  a(\partial_\mu \partial_\nu - g_{\mu \nu} \Box) \phi^2 $$
$$ = a (\Box \partial_\nu - \partial_\nu \Box) \phi^2$$

Now, is it true that

$$(\Box \partial_\nu - \partial_\nu \Box)=0  ? $$

Answer (score 1):

Your index positions are all messed up. Stick to the following rules:

1. In each term, each free index should be at the same height.

Example: $a_\nu+b^\nu$ is wrong, because the free index $\nu$ is in different heights. Correct would be $a^\nu+b^\nu$ or $a_\nu+b_\nu$.

2. Each pair of summation indices should be at different height.

Example: $\partial^\mu a^\mu$ is wrong, because the pair of summation indices is on the same height. Correctly, it would read: $\partial_\mu a^\mu$ or $\partial^\mu a_\mu$.

Comment: Now it makes much more sense! :) Regarding your question: Yes, it is true, according to Schwarz's theorem (symmetry of second derivatives): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives